# jQuery link with "Begins by" [attribute^='value'] intead of using a class

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

### Current workflow

We define the actions available, then create the internal API for it. For a simple example, let's say users can do *Like* in our page. So, when clicking on *like*, this page is triggered with a post:

```
/like/add/2573
```

Also, to remove it, this one is triggered:

```
/like/remove/2573
```

So, seeing this, we could argue that the anchor tags look like this:

```
<button data-href = "/like/add/2573" class = "like icon-like">Like</button>
```

I would normally use the class "like" or add a class as "like-button" or similar to be able to select it with jQuery with simple

```
$(".like-button").click(function(e){ /*AJAX*/ });
```

### Proposed alternative

Instead of adding the class only for the handler, and since the API is well defined, wouldn't this be more desirable?

```
$("[data-href^='/like']").click(function(e){ /*AJAX*/ });
```

### Caveats

Maybe the biggest problem would be performance. Also, the javascript seems to be tighter coupled with the html (in the normal case is the opposite, the html is coupled with the js) which I'm not sure if it's better or worse actually.

### Question

**Can you think of any other problem that might arise from this?** What are the cons? I am going to test this setup, and if it has performance issues to restore it to the original way, but wanted to know your opinion and whether anyone has tried something like this.

Comment: Why are you using a href to begin with ? Why not data-attributes if you don't use it as a link ?

Comment: What happens if I right click that link and open in new window?

Comment: You should be redirected to the same previous page, having liked the post if you are logged... but now I see the problem, no link should perform actions

Comment: Changed it to a `<button>` to avoid these sort of problems, still the question remains similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use any links, when you can apply class `.add` or `.remove` to ANY element, `data-id="2573"` and in Ajax just add that link part

```
<span class='add' data-id='2573'>Like it</span>
```

```js
var urlAdd = 'like/add', urlRemove = 'like/remove';

$(document).on('click', '.add, .remove', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).hasClass('add') ? urlAdd : urlRemove,
        data: {id: $(this).data('id')},
        /* ... */
    });
});
```

Links in one place only - simple to change url;
Code reuse for almost identical actions;
Easy way to switch button state `$(this).toggleClass('add').toggleClass('remove')`